# Resuming download in Browser

Tags: google-chrome, download

I was downloading Ubuntu CD image (~690 MB) using chrome's default download manager. After about 300 MB my internet connection got temporarily disconnected. Now is there any way I can resume the download from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are still in the same browser session, you can open the download manager and resume it normally. If you have closed Chrome and opened a new session, you cannot resume. For larger downloads I'd recommend using `wget` or using the torrent links provided on the Ubuntu website. That way it is much easier to continue if you are disconnected along the way.

Comment: I was in the same session, but still there is no resume option.. I guess I have to to download again :-(.. how on earth a modern browser like chrome doesn't support resume is beyond me.

Comment: Which mirror were you downloading from out of curiosity, I'll give it a go in Firefox.

Comment: you mean I can try to resume it in FF?

Comment: Firefox and Chrome operate differently in resuming downloads. You cannot resume a Chrome download in Firefox, but Firefox may handle it differently upon disconnection.